# Is there a way to make a clickable link in Excel to open a file in the same folder?

Tags: excel

I am working with a large spreadsheet of properties for a local organization. I have about 250 photographs that need to be somehow associated with a particular properties. I want to avoid just pasting them into Excel because it will make the spreadsheet much too large. Instead, I'd like to be able to insert a link into a cell, which when clicked will open a jpeg located in the same folder as the spreadsheet. I just added a column labeled "photo" that I would like to use for this purpose. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: if my answer did solve your problem, please take the time to mark it as the accepted answer.  That would help me out.  thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a hyperlink and just reference the local file.   Under the insert menu choose hyperlink.  Then in the popup choose existing file or webpage.

[Check out this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2468/create-a-hyperlink-to-another-document-in-an-excel-worksheet/)

You may also manually insert the hyperlink using this syntax:

```
=HYPERLINK("c:\\data\\myImage.jpg","Image here")
```

Of Course you can always calculate the image location using a formula - same goes for the description.

Example using a UNC on your network in case everyone does not have the same drive mapped (Also note that you can link any type file of course):

```
=HYPERLINK("\\\\mydomain\\data\\common\\mygroup\\Drawings\\ScriptedDrawing.jpg", "Latest document")
```

Comment: The asker want to open a jpeg located in the same folder as the spreadsheet.  So you can use `info("directory")` function to get the spreadsheet's directory.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I missed that.  Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

`=hyperlink(info("directory")&"jpg1.jpg")`